# GKE, how to set metrics server metric-resolution?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

The default metric-resolution is 30s, I want to change it to 5s.

Is this possible? Or is there any other way to get the CPU changes of node every 5 seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately editing the YAML of the deployment will not work as it will get reverted because of the Addon Manager that will reconcile the ressource (see the `addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: Reconcile` label of the metrics-server deployment). Moreover, metrics-server isn't part of the Addons that can be disabled [through the API](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.locations.clusters#Cluster.AddonsConfig), as you could have installed [your own instance](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/tree/master/charts/metrics-server).

One way of doing it would be to remove the annotation, but I wouldn't recommend it as its deployment is managed by Google and might cause trouble in your cluster in the future, but feel free to open a ticket to the support to ask them.

Also, keep in mind that according to the [metrics-server documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/tree/master/charts/metrics-server) :

> Default 60 seconds can be changed using `--metric-resolution` flag. We
> are not recommending setting values below 15s, as this is the
> resolution of metrics calculated by Kubelet.