# How can I set `--metric-resolution=15s` in Metrics Server on a GKE cluster?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I have an specific need which I have to set `--metric-resolution=15s` argument on metrics-server deployed.

But, under a gke cluster I can't do this. When I change the default value (--metric-resolution=30s), nothing happens because GKE blockes my change.

When I delete the annotations and labels related to gke addons (`.metadata.labels.addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode=Reconcile`, `.metadata.annotations.components.gke.io/layer=addon`) from metrics-server deployment, they are set again by the addon controller.

I didn't find any helpful information where I could find something related, only information like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77621418).

My client and server versions:
Client Version: v1.28.1
Server Version: v1.26.12-gke.1111000

My metrics server is on version v0.5.2.

Answer (score 1):

GKE is a managed solution. You cannot change a lot of system components. What you are noticing is how it's expected to work. There is a controller that makes sure some system components and some parameters are not changed but the user!

Comment: I understand perfectly the motivation behind this, but it's a need for us right now. But thanks your reply!

Answer (score 1):

The post you mentioned suggests disabling the Metric Server Addon.

You can use this command:

```
kubectl label namespace default \
    addonmanagement.kubernetes.io/mode=Disabled
```

After disabling the addon, you would be able to modify the configuration of Metrics Server manually. However, without the addon, Metrics Server will not receive automatic updates and upgrades provided by GKE.

If you want to customize Metrics Server while still utilizing GKE features, consider creating a Custom Resource Definition (CRD) and associated controller to manage Metrics Server deployments according to your desired configuration. This approach allows you to override the defaults without interfering with the managed environment.

See these links

[Custom Resources](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/)

[Controllers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubernetes/configure-pod-container-image-from-configmap/#create-a-controller-with-the-webhook-configuration)

Comment: Your reply was very useful. I'll follow these links. 

PS.: The second link is returning 404 error.